# Can Blender 2.79 Fluid Physics act on Rigid Body objects?

Tags: rigid-body-simulation, fluid-simulation

I'm trying to have a flow of water rotate a solid-body propeller in Blender 2.79.
But before I went any deeper, I got curious about a comment by a Blender Artist saying this:

> The fluid simulation does not interact with other objects but other objects can interact with the fluid sim. Set an object to be an obstacle in the fluid settings and you'll have to keyframe animate it's movement. It's movement will then interact with the fluid.

This was back in 2013. Is this statement still true today. If fluids can't help, can I use Particle Physics, or do I need to extend the current Physics Engine by code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sadly it's still valid. Nothing particularly important changed since then. Maybe Mantaflow fluid simulation could change something in the future: https://developer.blender.org/diffusion/B/browse/fluid-mantaflow/

Answer (score -1):

Yes!!!
After 2 days of work, I can finally say: It is Possible!
See the picture below.
[image]

You can watch the full animation Here on Youtube [11s Video](https://youtu.be/t7YVZdLfOPc)

By the way, no it is not a keyframed animation of the turbine that you are seeing. It is pure physics.

---

The author wrote under the linked youtube video:

> In Blender, Rigid Bodies effects on Fluids are very to implement. However, for long, the reverse interaction was dubbed impossible. No more! Using Blender Particles to emit particles, then converting them to rigid bodies and finally applying Cube Suffer on the resulting animation.
>
> In this video, I'm using a modified version of Cube Surfer to make able to utilize simple meshes (not particles as in the original version).
> If there's enough likes, I might post a detailed tutorial.

Comment: To make this answer useful please add a description of the steps you took to make this. Other users will not learn from your experience otherwise.