# How can I reduce the friction of Mantaflow colliding with effectors?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation, collision

Just experimenting with liquids in Blender (I’ve only just got into doing fluid sims). Finished this tutorial and did some experiments of my own with collision effectors, such as some whiskey dropping into a glass.

[image]

[collateralDamage02Fluid001RS.blend](https://blenderartists.org/uploads/short-url/5rQ8XbCzviunHUy4QrDrXFCaaoQ.blend) (946.6 KB)
However, one thing I’ve noticed is that there seems to be some weird interaction with the effector’s friction which lends the liquid a ‘soupy’ quality, where it seems to adhere to the side of the glass somewhat (see left of glass above). This also happens a little in the tutorial mentioned above.

I’ve played around with viscosity and other values, but I don’t seem to be able to get a satisfactory result (eg. the ‘liquid’ SHOULD quickly slide down the side of the glass surface). This behavior can be observed on the edges of the domain walls, but obviously that’s not ideal.

I’ve done a little reading around and pre-Mantaflow docs seem to mention a ‘slide’ value for colliders… but it doesn’t seem to turn up in the current settings.

If this is just an in-development feature or a current bug, that’s all good - happy to wait, everybody’s doing great work. But if I’m missing something and somebody can put me right, I’d really appreciate it.

Many thanks!

BONUS DUMB QUESTION:

Why can’t I resize my domain in edit mode? Resizing in object mode seems inconvenient, but edit resizing or applying scale really seems to screw up the fluid sims.